# Not sure if to keep this or not (noindex question)

Tags: seo

Community,

I found in my  tag the following piece of code.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,follow">
```

As far as I'm aware this will make sure that robots don't crawl my website, but I want them to crawl my website, how can I change this?

Kind Regards

Comment: Robots do crawl your site because they follow links (`follow`), but they don't index it (`noindex`).

Comment: Oh oke, thanks for clearing that. Now I need to find how to make sure they index it to. Otherwise my website wont show up on google etc decently.

Comment: Check both [Settings → Reading](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen) and SEO plugin settings, if you use one.

Comment: As for the reading pane, I think I got that covered. look at this: https://i.gyazo.com/144295a9620ccff3675c218f5b433cad.png but regarding plugin, I use yoast seo, maybe I have to check that

Comment: Keep in mind that Yoast's `robots` settings can come out to be on the per-post basis.

Comment: Yes, but I checked this on my homepage, and another two of my main pages, so I think it's everywhere :P

Answer (score 0):

The actual name depends on your locale but it's under settings => reading and should be called something like "prevent search engines from indexing my site".

Comment: Yes, I know that. You're referring to this option?

https://i.gyazo.com/144295a9620ccff3675c218f5b433cad.png
Sorry it's in Dutch.

The reason is, that was already "off", so that's why I don't really know where that line of code is coming from.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was talking about. I'd a) check whether it's hardcoded in the theme's header.php, b) search the theme's functions.php and c) look at any plugin that does SEO-related stuff.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a go

Comment: Yes, if your sitewide setting is to allow robots, then it's either a plugin or a theme that's adding this code.